# Hibernate: create mapping for property over multiple joined tables

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I have three tables (named A, B and C) in the database:

```
A
-----
ID
B_ID
-----
```

```
B
-----
ID
C_ID
-----
```

```
C
-----
ID
-----
```

Respectively, I have the classes A, B and C.

```
public class A{
    private Long id;
    private Long b_id;
}
```

```
public class B{
    private Long id;
    private Long c_id;
}
```

```
public class C{
    private Long id;
}
```

As you can see from the code for class "A", I have mapped the ID of the class B instead of the object, followingly:

```
<property name="b_id" column="B_ID" type="java.lang.Long" not-null="false">
```

Now I would need to do this for the ID of "C" as well, i.e. so that I can get the ID of A's associated C object directly with

`a.getC_id();`

How can I achieve this? This should be done so that when Hibernate reads the A object from the database, the ID of C is joined to the query, i.e. so that there are no extra queries or subqueries (a.getB().getC_id() is not acceptable).

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM. It's supposed to map tables to objects having associations with each other. You're not using it as it's intended to be used, and are thus fighting with the tool. You should use Hibernate as intended, or not use Hibernate at all.

Comment: Sometimes in real-life projects there are reasons for doing things in a non-standard way. I'm aware of "better" ways of achieving what I want, but due to various external reasons this is the way to go, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

First create a DTO object,

```
public class ADTO {
    private Long a_id;
    private Long b_id;
    private Long c_id;
    public ADTO(Long a_id,Long b_id,Long c_id){
       this.a_id = a_id;
       this.b_id = b_id;
       this.c_id = c_id;
    }
}
```

Now use the query,

`select new com.foo.ADTO(a.id,b.id,c.id) from A a, B b, C c where
a.id = b.a_id and b.id = c.b_id`

You can do this even with the class `A`, I have avoided because I am not sure if the relation ship between `A` and `C` id on to `one to one` or not. The DTO is always safe.

Read the API docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) or an example [here](http://jyops.blogspot.in/2011/09/hibernate-data-fetching-options.html) on how you can tune the HQL select.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation on ManuPK's answer, you could also put an instance of A into the DTO.

```
public class AWithCID {
    public final A a;
    public final cID;
    public AWithCID(A a, Long cID) { this.a = a; this.cID = cID; }
}

select new AWithCID(a, b.cID) from A a, B b where a.bID = b.id
```